# Evaluate the following integral. (double integral)

Tags: integration

I need help with this question please!

Integrate the following Integral:

$$\iint e^{x^2+y^2}dA$$ when D is the right half of the disk $x^2+y^2 \le1$

So this is what I did to solve it:

I drew out area D which looks like the right half of a circle of radius 1 centered around (0,0)

Then, by using intuition, I came up with the equation:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$

Which then gives me:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}[ 2x*e^{x^2+y^2}]_0
^1dy$$ then
$$\int_{-1}^{1}[ 2*e^{1+y^2}]dy$$ then
$$[4y*e^{1+y^2}]_{-1}^{1}$$

which eaquals $8e$.  But the answer is $\pi/2(e-1)$

Soooo. What did I do wrong?

Edit: So if I use polar co-ordinates:

$$\int_{-\pi/1}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$ 
and
$x^2+y^2=r^2$
so.
$$\int_{-\pi/1}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} e^{r^2}drd\theta$$

We then use u-sub: $ r^2=u, du=2rdr, dr=du/2r$

$$\int_{-\pi/1}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{u}}{2r}dud\theta$$

and now im stuck.

Comment: How does $\int e^{x^2+y^2}dx=2xe^{x^2+y^2}+c$?

Comment: OH yeah thanks! My bad, I did differentiation instead of integration -.-

Comment: Please compare your polar integral with my answer. You will see where you got wrong.

Comment: Why is there an extra r in the integral?

Comment: Your boundaries are wrong. That's a rectangle, not a half-circle

Answer (score 1):

Your integration limits have no variables. It is a rectangle instead of a disk. It's better to use polar coordinate, which gives you

$$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^1_0 e^{r^2}rdrd\theta$$

Comment: Why is there an extra r in the integral?

Comment: $r$ comes from the Jacobian determinant whenever you change Cartesian to polar coordinates.

Comment: See here for change of variable to polar coordinates: http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap4/Chap4-5/printversion.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Your boundaries of integral not right.

The integral should be
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$$
you can change to polar coordintes